# How to execute Callable in existing Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem. I have to create a `Scheduler.java` file, which contains `delegate` method with two parameters: `Thread thread, Callable<T> callable`. Callable have to be executed in thread used in parameter and also method `delegate` need to return result from `callable.call()` method.

I've tried to use `ExecutorService`, but I have no idea, how to use existing thread to run another task.

I have also code, that `Scheduler.java` should pass:

```
        final Scheduler s = new Scheduler();
        final Thread[] threads = new Thread[2];
        Thread lolek = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(s.delegate(threads[1], new Callable<String>() {
                        public String call() { return "Pat a " + Thread.currentThread(); }
                    }));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            public String toString() { return "Lolek"; }
        };
        Thread mat = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(s.delegate(threads[0], new Callable<String>() {
                        public String call() { return "Bolek i " + Thread.currentThread(); }
                    }));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            public String toString() { return "Mat"; }
        };
        threads[0] = lolek;
        threads[1] = mat;
        for (Thread t : threads) t.start();
```

And I created `Scheduler.java`:

```
public class Scheduler {
    Object value = "";
    public Scheduler() {  }

    public synchronized <T> T delegate(Thread thread, Callable<T> callable) {
        // magic here...
     }
}
```

Have anyone some thoughts, solutions etc.?
I'll be very grateful for any help :)

Comment: "Callable have to be executed in thread used in parameter" that looks like bad idea/mistake in design. Are you sure that this is what you are expected to do? Proper solution would involve using ExecutorService which ware designed to handle Collable tasks.

Comment: Maybe your `delegate` doesn't really expect Thread (maybe it need to create its own Thread), or maybe it is not expected to run Collable on that thread, but after task from Thread will be executed (because Thread and Collable can describe two tasks, independent from each other).

Comment: @Pshemo I also think that it looks like a bad idea/mistake in design. But I've got such specification from my professor. He wrote there, that method delegate should have Thread and Callable parameters and Callable should be executed using thread in first parameter. I tried to use ExecutorService, but how to use it to handle Callable task on already existing thread?

Comment: IMO best option is to ask professor for confirmation that this isn't mistake. There are too many problems with Thread. First of all, what he thinks should happen if passed thread has its own task like printing "hello world" every 2 seconds (note, every Thread has some task, even empty `run` method is a *some* task). Should that task be replaced? HOW? With reflection? What if Thread didn't accept Runnable describing task, but is Thread subclass which overrides its own `run()` method? It can't be done in such case. OR what if to `delegate` we pas Thread which already `start()` execution?

Comment: Other concern: if we agree that thread can't override its task, it means that it needs to know at time of its creation either (a) which Collable it should execute (which doesn't look right because why would we need to pass it as second argument then?) (b) way how to obtain passed Collable. Case (b) looks more probable. So method would need to store that Collable in some place like `List<Collable>` field and from that list each Thread would take one (first?) Collable to execute. But that also has potential problems, like what if two `delegate` methods ware called at same time?

Comment: Two Threads will try to `start()` at same time, but we don't know which will finish its preparation first, so when they run and take Collable it may happen that Thread2 will take Collable1 (from start of list). Is it acceptable? All those problems (and probably many more) ware already handled by ExecutorServices.

Comment: Re, "...how to use existing thread to run another task..." That's not possible in the general case. A thread runs the code that was provided when it was created, and there is no way for one thread to change what another thread is doing. But another thread can _ask_... In the _special_ case where the code that you have provided for a thread to run happens to be a loop that takes `Callable` objects from a queue and calls the `Call()` method of each one, then some other thread can put `Callable` objects into the queue, and the first thread will call them.  There's a name for that pattern, BTW:...

Comment: ...It's called a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I know about thread pool. I tried to use it, but as far as I know, I can't use existing thread. So I create new one, that is similar to this from parameter (the same name and toString method) and he runs callables from queue. But I'm still getting wrong answer or TLE when I'm sending my code...

here is a code of Scheduler.java: https://pastebin.com/gZQZ5AuA

Comment: I didn't mean to say that an actual thread pool would be an acceptable solution to your homework. I only meant to say that (a) there is no _general_ way for one thread to force another thread to do _anything_, and (b) If you create a _special_ thread, that is designed to call a given method of a given object upon request, then the thing that you have created will look a lot _like_ a thread pool. But, I don't really understand what the instructor is asking you to do. Pshemo suggested that you ask for clarification. That sounds like good advice to me.